# iFrames not executing in parallel

Tags: asp.net, iframe, parallel-processing

We are using 6 iFrames on our page. They fetch data from couple of external web services and an internal WCF service and display the data. There is a separate aspx page built for each of the iFrames. From our perf monitoring we found out that at any point only two threads are executing in parallel. Not all 6 threads get executed. What can probably be cause for this? Is there any restriction that more than 2 threads can't be created in parallel? Is there any configuration where I can change this?

Answer (score 3):

This is true of `IE6` and `IE7`.  Nothing to do with DNS. To simulate this, run three or more downloads simultaneously in IE and you will find that only two at a time are executed, the rest will wait. Different case with Firefox, which I believe is 6 - worth checking.

Answer (score 0):

Most web browsers set limits on the amount of threads that will be used concurrently for rendering elements. I believe the default is 2 for many web browsers. So what you are seeing is correct, the browser itself is only requesting 2 objects at a time.

Comment: Thanks for responding. Will XMLHttpRequest solve the problem? I guess even then the browser restricts this. Is it possible to change this behavior?

Answer (score 0):

Most browsers will only make two requests at a time from each domain.

If the requests aren't session-less, only one requests at a time from each user is handled by the server, other requests from the same user are queued.

Comment: Thanks. Is there any way to get around this?

Comment: @KPK: You can set up aliases for your domain, so that the browser thinks that they are separate domains.

Comment: thanks. I tried setting up aliases using IIS. But I can't browse to the pages under the original folder. I get a host can't be resolved error. Do I need to tweek DNS for this? Any step-by-step article will be of great help. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

IIS has an upper limit on the number of concurrent threads it will execute, the rest will get queued until the first two are finished.  A phenomenon I've run into as well when using callbacks.

Comment: Thanks. Is there any way to change this default behavior?

Answer (score 0):

If you make your iframes point to different DNS then the browser should parallelize them all.

See here:  http://www.websiteoptimization.com/speed/tweak/parallel/

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem too. You might be hitting a session lock in ASP.NET.

In short set EnableSessionState in the @ Page directive to ReadOnly.

I found it from this answer which deserves the credit:-
[IIS Express 7.5 not processing requests concurrently](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9672566/iis-express-7-5-not-processing-requests-concurrently/9675215#)