# How to keep ASP.NET session during long request processing?

Tags: asp.net, iis-7.5, session-state, session-timeout

The scenario is following:

1. A user clicks to download a complex report that takes long time to complete (longer than the session timeout is).
2. After the report is completed, user clicks on any other link, but the session is expired.

The user is wondering why the session has expired during the long running request.

How to tell ASP.NET not to expire session during the request? (To start counting the session timeout after the request is completed.)

**UPDATE:** The solution should work without JavaScript.

Comment: Depending on how the report generation/download happens, you could do... Click to start report generation / Display a "report being generated" page which sends ajax requests to check on report generation and thus preserves the session. When the report generation is complete, redirect to a page which actually does the download.

Comment: The solution should work without javascript.

Comment: TN I'm not aware of any way to do so - others may know of something, perhaps through implementing your own http request handler - but certainly the "standard" http pipeline handles the session stuff before your code is called. You _may_ be able to move your generation earlier in page lifecycle - is this MVC or Webforms? When exactly are you generating your report (`Page_Load`/???)

Answer (score 5):

A web application *should* respond to requests in a timely manner.  I would argue that the actual problem isn't that the session is timing out, it's that a long-running process is happening in-line when it should be off-loaded to the back-end.

Instead of making the user wait for the report, kick off a process on the server to generate the report and respond to the user with a response indicating that their requests has been queued and is being processed, and that their report will be ready when the process is complete.

The user can then continue to navigate the website, use the application, etc.  When the report is done, there are various ways you can notify the user.  The application can send them an email, perhaps even with the report attached.  Or there can be some in-application notification system (like the Facebook notifier) which would either have an AJAX polling mechanism or (in response to your update about not using JavaScript) could be more passive and simply notify them on their first page request following the completion of the report.

In any event, any process which takes this long shouldn't be in-line in a web application.

**Edit:** As a proposed setup, you could do the following:

1. When the user requests the report, add a record to a queue table which includes any information needed to begin generating the report.
2. Return application control to the user.
3. Write a Windows Service or scheduled console application which polls the queue table and processes any reports in that table.
4. As each report finishes, update its status in the table.
5. Optionally also have the service/application notify the user (email, add a record to a table that drives an in-app notification system on the website, etc.).
6. The user can follow the notification to download the report, or just check back their "report queue" in the website.

Comment: I known, but problem is the budget:)

Comment: If the client will pay it that it will be ok. The question is not what is the scholarly best solution, but how to tell ASP.NET/IIS start counting the session after the response is finished.

Comment: @TN.: Fair enough, though I would still argue that such a solution would be more of a hack than a real solution.  It's analogous to a client saying, "We have a hammer, and we need to cut some wood.  There's room in the budget for a saw next year, but in the meantime we want you to find a way to do it with the hammer."  The stated problem is "how do I cut wood with a hammer?" but the _real_ problem is one step higher than that.

Answer (score 0):

What does take long time, the generation of the report or the download of the file? 
If the operation take to much time you'll probably get an page timeout, your method took too long to respond.

If the session expire because the file requested from the user takes to long to download, then this is a normal behaviour. The user request the file and he looks non active until the next request, the session doesn't get refreshed and it expires.

Comment: Fortunately, the generation. If download there could be a problem with proxies that would be caching the response already.

Answer (score 0):

You could manually extend the session timeout for the particular session by setting the [HttpSessionState.Timeout](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.sessionstate.httpsessionstate.timeout.aspx) value during report generation (possibly multiple times).

This does seem a little clunky, however, assumes you'd always be able to know in advance how long to increase it by, and you'd need to make sure you set it back afterwards or you'd end up with visitors who've generated a report having different timeouts to those who haven't

While this might work, it's certainly not the best approach and you really should have this run as an asynchronous task.

Comment: Can you clarify how/why it doesn't work? It doesn't work if called from inside your handler? Doesn't work if called anywhere on your site? I hesitate to suggest it 'cos it's nasty but if it only doesn't work from inside the handler, you could do Click Link->Redirect to page which set timeout->Redirect to real generate report page. Unfortunately, we're moving from nasty to downright fugly

Comment: Thanks for hints. Is it possible to get from ASP.NET / IIS how many request are actually being processed? Or I have to count them, in order to restore the timeout after all requests has been processed?

Comment: I [believe you'll find](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9675215/156755) that while using sessions, a second request by the same user is queued until the first completes as each request needs exclusive access to the session. This obviously only applies to resources which are executed, not images/css/etc

Comment: I was trying that but multiple requests (not static) by the same user were running in parallel and were no waiting for the first long-running request.