# Loading 2 iframes at same time

Tags: c#, asp.net, html, iframe, iis-7

I've started develope a webchat in .Net 4 on IIS 7. Main page of chat contains 2 IFRAME. First frame uses for reserving messages and loads progressively(it loads and deliver messages to chat all time user connected to chat). Second iframe uses to send messages. I have a problem when first frame loading second frame couldn't be loade but if first frame stops load the seconds executes in milliseconds.

1. I already tried:
2. Use AJAX to send messages.
3. Use different names for scripts of first frame and second frame. It helps sometimes but not always.
4. Check if scripts still runned after user refresh chat's main page or close it.
5. Setting connection timeout in IIS.
6. Use streamed resonse/text response.
7. Connection keep-alive/no keep alive directive.
8. Swap Iframe tags of main chat page.
9. Add CSS JS files fo chat's main page in different ways i.e. @import CSS.
10. Remove treading using.

***I found a sollution but I don't think this is good solution to use many domains because domain access javascript restrictions.
[iFrames not executing in parallel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3389086/iframes-not-executing-in-parallel)***

Here is Test.aspx and Test.aspx.cs page code:

```
<%@ Page Title="Home Page" Language="C#"  AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="Test.aspx.cs" Inherits="Test._Default" %>

using System;
using System.Web;
using System.Threading;

namespace Test
{
    public partial class _Default : System.Web.UI.Page
    {
        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
        string p = (Request.QueryString["p"] != null)?Request.QueryString["p"]:"";
        if(Request.QueryString["data"] == null)
        {
            Response.Write(@"<html><head></head><body>12<iframe src=""Test.aspx?data="" height=""900px""></iframe><iframe src=""http://localhost/Test"+p+@".aspx?data=""  height=""900px""></iframe></body></html>");   
        }
        else
        {
            System.IO.File.AppendAllText(Server.MapPath(".")+ @"\test.log", DateTime.Now.ToString()+ "\t" + "Data script started\r\n");
            Response.Write(new String(' ', 1024));
            int i=0;
            while (Response.IsClientConnected)
            {
                Response.Write((++i).ToString() + " ");
                Response.Flush();
                Thread.Sleep(1000);
                System.IO.File.AppendAllText(Server.MapPath(".")+ @"\test.log", DateTime.Now.ToString()+ "\t" + "Data script Runned\r\n");

            }
            System.IO.File.AppendAllText(Server.MapPath(".")+ "test.log", DateTime.Now.ToString()+ "\t" + "Data script stoped\r\n");
        }
    }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Have you considered looking at the SignalR (beta) package in NuGet - its custom built for writing this kind of application and has similarities with Node.js. I strongly advise you consider looking into this technology to solve this problem.

It can be found here on git hub https://github.com/SignalR/SignalR and here on Nuget http://nuget.org/packages/SignalR .